# Forcing suspended jobs to swap all memory in Ubuntu

Tags: memory-management, ubuntu, swap

Is is possible to suspend a job and force all of its memory to swap?

I've got six jobs running, and they're competing with each other for resources. So much gets wasted on system swapping that they run forever. If I could suspend three (and dump their allocated memory to disk) the remaining three could run normally. Once those finish, I could resume the others, and the total run time would be fine.

Comment: I doubt you need to explicitly for the memory to swap. Try just suspending the job (e.g. with bash's `suspend`) and see if their memory is swapped out.

Comment: I think you're right... maybe you should turn that into an answer?